# Ordinal numbers arithmetic $((1 + \omega) + \omega) \cdot \omega$ Cantor Normal Form

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

how do you get the Cantor Normalform of
$$((1 + \omega) + \omega) \cdot \omega$$
This would be $$((1 + \omega) + \omega) \cdot \omega = (\omega + \omega) \cdot \omega = (\omega \cdot 2) \cdot \omega$$ right? Is the attempt correct like this? How to proceed?

Comment: You have a typo in the middle of the second equation line, where it should be $\omega + \omega$ instead of $\omega \cdot \omega$.  It is corrected at the next equals sign.

Comment: Yes, sorry, now the question is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: Remember that ordinal multiplication is associative, so $(\omega\cdot2)\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot(2\cdot\omega)$, so you can simplify a bit more.

Comment: Ah okay, perfect, thank you Asaf Karagila